# Wrapper div for image containing text cannot both change brightness filter on image AND change opacity filter on text

Tags: html, css

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="featuredWrapper">
    <div id="featuredContentWrapper">
        <div class="ContentThumbnail">
            <a>
                <div class="ContentThumbnailCaption">
                    <h3>Lorem</h3>
                    <p>Ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/200/300.jpg" class="ContentThumbnailImage" />

            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #featuredWrapper
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:13.85%;
        margin-right:13.85%;
        width:72.3%;
        /*BORDER*/
        border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
        /*ANIMATION*/
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
    #featuredContentWrapper
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        text-align:center;
    }
    .ContentThumbnail
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        display:inline-block;
        height: 30%;
        width: 22.5%;
        margin: 2% 4% 2% 4%;
        /*VISUAL*/
        background-color:aqua;
        /*ANIMATION*/
        transition: 0.3s;
    }
     .ContentThumbnail:hover .ContentThumbnailCaption
    { 
       /*VISUAL*/
       filter:opacity(100%);
    }
    .ContentThumbnail:hover .ContentThumbnailImage
    {
       /*VISUAL*/
       filter:brightness(50%);
    }      
    .ContentThumbnail a
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
    }
    .ContentThumbnailImage
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        display:inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ContentThumbnailCaption
    {
        /*SETUP*/
        position:absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        /*VISUAL*/
        color:white;
        filter:opacity(0);
        /*ANIMATION*/
        transition:0.3s;         
    }
```

I would like for the brightness and opacity changes to occur concurrently, so that the text would display over the darkened image. 
As it stands now, I think either the brightness filter is somehow hiding the text or the effects are occurring one after another because when you stop hovering, the text will appear and play the fading out animation.

I have tried changing the mechanisms used to do both effects, like using visibility CSS instead of filters. I haven't tried JavaScript yet, but I would like to keep this effect within CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed for below mentioned css

```
 .ContentThumbnail:hover .ContentThumbnailCaption
{ 
   /*VISUAL*/
   filter:opacity(100%);z-index:1;
}
```

```css
#featuredWrapper {
  /*SETUP*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 13.85%;
  margin-right: 13.85%;
  width: 72.3%;
  /*BORDER*/
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
  /*ANIMATION*/
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#featuredContentWrapper {
  /*SETUP*/
  text-align: center;
}

.ContentThumbnail {
  /*SETUP*/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30%;
  width: 22.5%;
  margin: 2% 4% 2% 4%;
  /*VISUAL*/
  background-color: aqua;
  /*ANIMATION*/
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.ContentThumbnail:hover .ContentThumbnailCaption {
  /*VISUAL*/
  filter: opacity(100%);
  z-index: 1;
}

.ContentThumbnail:hover .ContentThumbnailImage {
  /*VISUAL*/
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.ContentThumbnail a {
  /*SETUP*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ContentThumbnailImage {
  /*SETUP*/
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.ContentThumbnailCaption {
  /*SETUP*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*VISUAL*/
  color: white;
  filter: opacity(0);
  /*ANIMATION*/
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="featuredWrapper">
  <div id="featuredContentWrapper">
    <div class="ContentThumbnail">
      <a>
        <div class="ContentThumbnailCaption">
          <h3>Lorem</h3>
          <p>Ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/200/300.jpg" class="ContentThumbnailImage" />

      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```